# Netflix and my browser(s) playing up

Tags: browser

For some reason whenever I watch Netflix and only Netflix (amazon prime video works fine) my browser randomly glitches and crashes browser and/or PC. If just Netflix errors its just D7377 error code.

I have tried reinstalling my OS and updated drivers and it doesn't work. I even had this problem on my old graphics card. I have a MSI 3070 now but I did have a ASUS 1070 TI and it still happened there.

(top bar goes missing and blank until I hover my mouse over it)
[image: Browser goes black randomly]

Comment: What operating system?  What browser re you using?  What version of that browser?  What version of that operating system?  Netflix uses an entirely different codec than Amazon.  Are you by chance dragging the tab to another display?  Is `Use hardware acceleration` enabled or disabled?

Comment: I have tried hardware on and off. Using firefox/edge/chrome all same or similar problems. Windows 10

Comment: Try to disable the adblocker (if you have one).

Comment: I have tried that even in icognito mode with everything disabled